# How to use an .aspx form for a workflow step in SharePoint 2010

Tags: infopath

I'd like to implement email templates in SharePoint 2010 and found this great video tutorial on how to implement it using SharePoint Designer:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6ifiMNt_cg

Basically, I need exactly what is shown in that video, so I'm trying to re-do the steps in the video, which is based on SharePoint 2007, into our SharePoint 2010 environment.

The part where I get stuck is the "send email" workflow form. In the video, the author is editing the send email workflow form as an .ASPX. As such, he is able to drag a list (the email templates list) on to it and make a webpart connection.

I noticed though that in SharePoint2010, following these exact steps leads to the creation of an Infopath form for the "send email" workflow step. And on this infopath form, I can't drag the email templates list or make a webpart connection.

So my question is...in SharePoint 2010, can I use an .aspx instead of the default infopath form for a workflow step? I can't use Visual Studio or custom coding, I'm limited to basic configuration and SharePoint designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either an InfoPath form or an .aspx page as the form for your workflow.

I am not sure what you mean by using an aspx as a workflow step though.

For making web part connections in SharePoint designer, check out this video http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/video-create-web-part-connections-using-sharepoint-designer-2010-VA102191896.aspx

I was unable to find a quick tutorial on email templates in SharePoint designer for 2010 and I am only familiar with how to do something like that in code, not the designer.

Comment: "You can use either an InfoPath form or an .aspx page as the form for your workflow." How though? In this case a infopath form was created automatically for the workflow action. How can I switch to it being an aspx?

Comment: I'm sorry I have actually never used an .aspx page in a workflow, I just know that you can as I have seen them used in workflows before and also read in "Inside SharePoint 2010" by Ted Pattinson and Andrew Connell that you can use aspx pages in workflows.

Comment: Perhaps this will get you started. http://www.novolocus.com/2008/06/25/sharepoint-workflow-with-aspx-forms/

Comment: Thanks for thinking along Meyer. Unfortunately, that blog entry is mostly a rambling of how he did not get something to work :)

Comment: I do know if you have a document library with a workflow attached to it, you can set the workflow to kick off any time an item is added or modified. These items can include a .aspx page.